# Executing / running multiple php cron scripts from one cron job

Tags: php, shell, include, cron, exec

I'm trying to setup a PHP file as a cron job, where that PHP file includes/executes/runs other PHP files. I am trying to achieve this because my host only allows 5 cron jobs total for the all the domains hosted, so I'm trying to compile tasks into certain cron jobs.

The file i'm running via a cron job itself is located at

```
/home/XXXXX/data/cron/tasks/run.php
```

--

The include files are at

```
/home/XXXXX/domains/domain.co.uk/html/cms/apps/scripts/twitter.php  
/home/XXXXX/domains/domain.com/html/generator/runcrawl.php 
/home/XXXXX/domains/domain.net/html/cms/apps/scripts/sitemap.php
```

--

How do I include that config file from run.php? I've tried doing `include_once('/home/XXXXX/domains/domain.co.uk/html/cms/apps/scripts/twitter.php ');` but returned errors.

I have also tried adding using the following in the run.php but no luck!

```
exec('php /home/XXXXX/domains/domain.co.uk/html/cms/apps/scripts/twitter.php');
exec('php /home/XXXXX/domains/domain.com/html/generator/runcrawl.php');
exec('php /home/XXXXX/domains/domain.net/html/cms/apps/scripts/sitemap.php');
```

--

The cron job setup through the control panel is the following, which I know is correct

```
php /home/XXXXXX/data/cron/tasks/run.php
```

I'm not sure if this could be easily done via a shell script instead? Any thoughts please?

Comment: Are you sure the host will let you access files across the domain directories like that? What does `var_dump(is_readable('/home/XXXXX/domains/domain.com/html/generator/runcrawl.php'));` tell you?

Comment: new host\vps why make life hard for your self.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unlikely your limited host will allow you to cross domain folders like that as it can be a security issue.
If you cannot access files across directories, then consider getting the initial cron job to call other files using php's cURL.
The downside of this method is that the files must be in the public html directory.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a shell script. Open your text editor and do this:

```
#!/bin/bash

wget -q /home/XXXXX/domains/domain.co.uk/html/cms/apps/scripts/twitter.php

sleep 5

wget -q /home/XXXXX/domains/domain.com/html/generator/runcrawl.php 

sleep 5

wget -q /home/XXXXX/domains/domain.com/html/generator/runcrawl.php
```

This will execute the php script using the [wget command](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_wget.htm) in quiet mode. And will add a 5 second pause between scripts.

Save it as `any_name.sh` and upload it to your server, remember to give execute permission to all the files and add it to your cron job.